# Git pull origin created a Issue

Tags: git, github, repository, git-svn

git newbie in here.

I had 2 branches a and b in my local repo. 
so if i do

```
git branch
*a
b
```

then by mistake i did "git pull origin" and it pulled a bunch of files and messed my working environment on branch a.

I wanted to revert back. I wanted to undo "git pull origin" - how can i do that??

I tried "git pull origin a" but then it gives me hundreds of files to be merged and it gives the following message after a big list of files:

Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm '
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.

I tried "git reset --hard" but this doesn't bring the files that I wanted to work on. What can i do to fix this??

One piece of info that might help: before doing "git pull origin" the response to "git log" was commits of my team only (which was working on that branch only) but now after i did "git pull origin" the result of "git log" is status from everyone in the company.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try resetting waaaaay back and the pull branch a

```
git reset --hard HEAD^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(add more ^ if you need to go back even more commits)

and then pull

```
git pull origin a
```

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhhhhhh!!!! you made my dayyyyyy. (i'm copying syntax from ur solution)

Comment: This would not revert to the local state from before the pull. It would put the local state to the state from the remote.

Comment: Also are better ways to refer to commits some number of commits back, by using `HEAD~2` would be the same as `HEAD^^`, and you can just increase the number to increase the number of commits that you look back.

Comment: Beautiful idea qqx. I like it. But my local was clean- I didn't have any code that I wanted to commit. My problem was - I couldn't continue working because my local directories got messed up from pulling some other files. So it was good solution for my case.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have pull configured to do rebase your local changes on top of the changes from the remote, using pull will have merged your changes with the commits from the remote. As long as you haven't done any further commits, that would leave the `HEAD` ref pointed at the merge commit created by your pull operation. That commit will have two parents, the commit which was your state before the merge, and the commit which was the state of the remote branch before the merge. Those can be referred to by the names `HEAD^` and `HEAD^2` respectively.

You can get back to your local state before the pull by using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This will blow away any uncommitted changes you have to tracked files, if there's anything like that which you want keep you can use `git stash` to save them.

It would also be a good idea to run `git branch savepoint` before doing the reset to save the current status just in case the reset makes things worse.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect use case for [the reflog](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html). The reflog stores a history of where your head and the heads of your branches where in the past. Run [`git reflog`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) and you will see. In your case the proper command is probably `git reflog a`. This will show you past states of your `a` branch. Look for the correct line and then do a `git reset`.

If you just did the pull and did nothing else, the command is `git reset --hard a@{1}`. That means “revert the current current branch to the state of `a` one change ago”. If you did more changes you will probably have to go further (eg. `git reset --hard a@{4}`.

This is way more convenient and controllable than going for `HEAD^^^^^…`.

Comment: Sweet! I liked this. This one is more readable than going back ^^^^ times. Good thing to learn. So +1 for your answer.